# Speeding Up Bash Scripts

Tags: bash, optimization

I'm writing a semi-realtime bash script and it's not running quite fast enough. From what I understand, Bash references some sort of table to find the full path of the commands you feed it. Would specifying the full path significantly speed up commands that are run in a loop?

Comment: You can try it yourself and see.  Run your script, see how long it takes, and try it again with the paths specified, and see if it takes less time.

Comment: If you're looking for ways to speed it up, then instead of making a guess at "Will this help?", paste the entire script and then let us identify likely hotspots or things you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: It is external processes that are the greatest overhead in most shell scripts. For example, if you want a list of files don't use `ls`, use `echo *`, any use of `cat` is probably unwarented, and so on.  You can't avoid external programs completely, but minimise their use as much as possible (and that will reduce PATH searches as well).

Answer (score 8):

Unlikely. The `bash` shell actually caches executables that it finds so only the first search will be slow.

From the `bash` manpage:

> If  the  name  is  neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, bash searches each element of the PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that name.  Bash uses a hash table to remember the  full  path names of executable files (see hash under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  A full search of the directories in PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table.

Speeding up `bash` scripts usually takes the form of two things:

- using bash internal stuff instead of spawning processes (like `cut` or `sed`) where the workload is small; and
- making better choices where you have to spawn external processes.

---

As an example of the first, extracting the first character of a string with:

```
firstchar=$(echo $string | cut -c1-1)
```

is a horrible idea since it must spawn processes to do the work. You can do the exact same thing in `bash` quickly with something like:

```
firstchar=${string:0:1}
```

*without* the relatively massive cost of spawning subprocesses.

The second point is just ensuring you choose the best tool for the job, when running subprocesses. For example, don't use a massive pipeline of multiple `grep`, `cut` and `sed` commands  when it can be done with a very simple `awk` one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been said about optimizing `bash` scripts, another option is not to use `bash` but a more lightweight shell instead (say, `sh`): `bash` is large and has a comparably long startup time.  If your script's execution time is short, it could actually be dominated by the `bash` startup.